# how to run the uwp miracast in background on minimizing window to avoid suspended state

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, screencast, miracast

I am developing a screen casting application for Windows systems, utilizing Miracast technology. The primary goal is to ensure that the application runs continuously in the background and actively monitors the casting connection. Whenever a casting interruption occurs, the application should automatically initiate a recast process. I have successfully implemented this functionality using a Windows UWP (Universal Windows Platform) application and incorporated a timer watchdog feature to monitor the casting system.

However, there is an issue with the UWP application when it comes to running in the background. The problem arises because the timer appears to get stuck when the application transitions from the foreground to the background. This behavior disrupts the continuous monitoring and recasting functionality.

Now, I am seeking a potential solution to this problem. Is there a way to transform the screen casting functionality into a Windows service application? By doing so, I hope to ensure that the application can seamlessly operate in the background of Windows systems without experiencing the issues that arise with UWP applications. This would provide a more robust and reliable solution for monitoring and managing casting interruptions.

I have successfully implemented this functionality using a Windows UWP (Universal Windows Platform) application and incorporated a timer watchdog feature to monitor the casting system. However, there is an issue with the UWP application when it comes to running in the background.

https://www.linkedin.com/in/karthik-kovi-8642a3212/

Comment: please do not post the same question again - it is too broad anyway and both will probably be closed - be more specific